# Items in array are returned in only one JSX element using .map()

Tags: arrays, reactjs, select, jsx, dropdown

New to react and still learning. I have an assignment to create a filter component with three dropsdowns that takes information from a JSON file. The idea is the results in the second dropdown will be filtered once the first dropdown has a selected value. The JSON format is:

```
"destinations": [
        {
            "id": 8375,
            "name": "Bordeaux",
            "country": "France",
            "category": "wine"
        }, ETC

"seasonCategories": {
        "spring": [
            "wine",
            "wonder",
            "forest",
            "adventure",
            "food"
        ], ETC
```

I've created a function that feeds the data into the dropdown component and filters it, but it's not returning as I expect: it's creating only one JSX `<option>` element with the values of all array items listed inside. I need it to generate a new JSX element with the current value of every item in the array. If I call `{el[index]}` on the last map function I get the right value, so I'm lost as to why it's not generating each in their own `<option>` tag. The function I'm using is:

```
function funcCategories(src, val) {
  return Object.keys(src)
    .filter((flag) => {
      return flag === val;
    })
    .map((el) => {
      let v = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < src[el].length; i++) {
        v.push(src[el][i]);
      }
      return v;
    })
    .map((el) => {
      return <option className="Dropdown__option">{el}</option>;
    });
}
```

My Dropdown component:

```
import React from 'react';

class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.value = '';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Dropdown__wrapper">
        <label className="Dropdown__label">{this.props.label}</label>
        <select
          className="Dropdown__select"
          value={this.props.value}
          onChange={this.props.handleSelect}
        >
          <option className="Dropdown__option">{this.props.label}</option>
          {this.props.func}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dropdown;
```

For you visual thinkers, this is what I'm seeing in the window:
[Dropdown result of my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q00Ao.png)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I was pushing the array object in the .filter() method and not the elements of each. Not the cleanest code but it works:

```
let keys = Object.keys(src);
let j = [];
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
if (keys[i] === val) {
alert(keys[i] + ' === ' + src[keys[i]].length)
for (let h = 0; h < src[keys[i]].length; h++) {
j.push(src[keys[i]][h]);
}
    }
  }
  return j.map((el) => {
        return <option className="Dropdown__option">{el}</option>;
      });
```